# Not enough background filtering

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to filter the background of images presenting electric cables. I tried to do the following:

1. Transform from color to gray
2. Apply `cv2.Laplacian` or 2 times of `cv2.Sobel` for finding edges in both directions.
3. Apply thresholding `cv2.THRESH_BINARY(_INV)`, `cv2.THRESH_OTSU`
4. Lastly, I tried to find edges with 'filtered' images using `cv2.Canny` together with `cv2.HoughLinesP`

Overall, the results aren't satisfying at all. I will give an example of 2 images:
[image: Text]

[image: Text]

And the output of my script:

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

I also played with the values in `config`, but the results weren't different much.

Here's the little script I managed to do:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def img_show(images, cmap=None):
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 10))
  root = 3 # len(images) ** 0.5
  for i, img in enumerate(images):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(root, root, i + 1)
    ax.imshow(img, cmap=cmap[i])
  plt.show()


class Config:
  scale = 0.4
  min_threshold = 120
  max_threshold = 200
  canny_min_threshold = 100
  canny_max_threshold = 200


config = Config()


def find_lines(img, rgb_img):
  dst = cv2.Canny(img, config.canny_min_threshold, config.canny_max_threshold)

  cdstP = np.copy(rgb_img)

  lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dst, 1, np.pi / 180, 150, None, 0, 0)

  lines1 = lines[:, 0, :]
  for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines1[:]:
    cv2.line(cdstP, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 5)
  return cdstP


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bgr_img = cv2.imread('DJI_0009.JPG')

    bgr_img = cv2.resize(bgr_img, (0, 0), bgr_img, config.scale, config.scale)

    rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # _, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray_img, config.min_threshold, config.max_threshold, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    # laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(rgb_img, cv2.CV_8UC1)
    sobelx = cv2.Sobel(gray_img, cv2.CV_8UC1, 1, 0)
    sobely = cv2.Sobel(gray_img, cv2.CV_8UC1, 0, 1)
    blended = cv2.addWeighted(src1=sobelx, alpha=0.5, src2=sobely, beta=0.5, gamma=0)

    _, threshold = cv2.threshold(blended, config.min_threshold, config.max_threshold,
                                 cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    p1 = find_lines(threshold, rgb_img)
    p2 = find_lines(blended, rgb_img)
    p3 = find_lines(gray_img, rgb_img)

    plots = [rgb_img, p1, p2, p3]
    cmaps = [None] + ['gray'] * (len(plots) - 1)
    img_show(plots, cmaps)
```

I am assuming I need to do much better filtring. However, I also tried image segmentation, but the results weren't promising at all.
Any ideas on how to improve this?
Thanks

Comment: I would suggest you use an appropriate threshold and then compute contours and filter on area and some measure of length or use connected components to filter on aspect and area.

Comment: Would you elaborate `on filter on area and some measure of length or use connected components to filter on aspect and area`. What kind of filtering should I look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV. I threshold, then optionally clean with morphology. Then get the contours and for each contour compute its rotated rectangle. Then get the dimensions of the rotated rectangle and compute the aspect ratio (largest dimension / smallest dimension) and optionally the area. Then I threshold on the aspect ratio (and optionally the area) and keep only those contours that pass)

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("DCIM-100-MEDIA-DJI-0009-JPG.jpg")
hh, ww = image.shape[:2]

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# create a binary thresholded image
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 64, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# invert so line is white on black background
thresh = 255 - thresh

# apply morphology
kernel = np.ones((11,11), np.uint8)
clean = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get external contours
contours = cv2.findContours(clean, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

area_thresh = ww / 2
aspect_thresh = ww / 30
print(area_thresh,aspect_thresh)
print('')
result = image.copy()
for c in contours:
    
    # get rotated rectangle from contour
    # get its dimensions
    rotrect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
    (center), (dim1,dim2), angle = rotrect
    maxdim = max(dim1,dim2)
    mindim = min(dim1,dim2)
    area = dim1 * dim2
    if mindim != 0:
        aspect = maxdim / mindim
    #print(area, aspect)

    #if area > area_thresh and aspect > aspect_thresh:
    if aspect > aspect_thresh:
        # draw contour on input
        cv2.drawContours(result,[c],0,(0,0,255),3)
        print(area, aspect)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("DCIM-100-MEDIA-DJI-0009-JPG_thresh.jpg",thresh)
cv2.imwrite("DCIM-100-MEDIA-DJI-0009-JPG_clean.jpg",clean)
cv2.imwrite("DCIM-100-MEDIA-DJI-0009-JPG_result.jpg",result)

# display result
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("clean", clean)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thresholded image:

[image]

Morphology cleaned image:

[image]

Result image:

[image]